# How to remove words from text file in Python that contain certain letter?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and need to remove lines from text file in Python that contain a certain letter. i.e. a text file containing the months of the year and I want to remove the months containing an r. I'm completely lost.

Comment: use `fileinput` module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? (Reads from stdin, writes to stdout.)

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    if 'r' not in line:
        print(line)
```

Sample usage:

```
$ python program.py < months_file > months_without_r_file
```